# Run scripts in a folder from "Run Application" launcher in ubuntu

Tags: gnome, scripts

I have some bash scripts in my ~/bin folder. I have added this folder to my PATH variable in ~/.bashrc, so I can run them from terminal easily. But **I want to run them by simply typing them in the "Run Application" launcher** (Alt + F2).

I am not looking for adding a launcher for a single script. I want to put my scripts in a folder and run it using the "Run Application" dialog by typing script name.

"Run Application" dialog image:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts you put in your `~/bin folder` *should* run by simply typing their name, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>however:

- If the image is from your computer (which I doubt, it seems an old one): simply type the scriptname, not necessary to include the path (which would be wrong in this example, since the script is in `~/bin`, not in `/usr/sbin`, like in your image.
- Make sure the script is executable
- if you (need to) run the script with `sudo` privileges, you should install `gksu` first:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gksu
  ```

  and the run them with the command:

  ```
  gksu <scriptname>
  ```

  (As mentioned: I assume the image is not from your computer)

  *Explanation:*

  Since you do not run the script in a terminal, you should give Ubuntu another way to ask for your password, like `gksu`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The image is not from my computer. I didn't type the complete script name yesterday, but when I was typing the name it was not auto completing. It was, may be, because I updated the PATH variable to include ~/bin in my ~/.bashrc but did not logout or restart. Today (I had restarted the PC), I typed and it was autocompleting :)

Comment: There is one more issue. Say my script name is "mountWindowPartition". When I type "mount", it does not autocomplete, probably because there is another binary "mount" in the system. It doesn't even show the list of options related to "mount" in the window (expanded after click "Show list of know applications"). So, basically I need to remember/type the name of script. Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: @ParveenKumar what I would do is rename the script to mount_WindowPartition. The moment you typed mount_, you can autocomplete :) however, the same goes for mountW.